# gnome-software Unable to get list of updates: Failed to update metadata for lvfs: checksum failure

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, upgrade, checksum

I sometimes use `gnome-software` to check for updates on `Debian`. My repositories are Debian Stable, Flathub and a few others each dedicated to a single program. When I do `sudo apt-get update` on Terminal my system is able to reach all repositories managed by it without issues and I can `sudo apt-get upgrade` just fine. However when I go to `gnome-software`, move to the `Updates` tab and click `Refresh`, I get the following error time to time:

```
Unable to get list of updates: Failed to update metadadta for lvfs: checksum failure: failed to verify data, expected [HASH]
```

Is this something to worry about?

Comment: step 1: research "Failed to update metadata for lvfs: checksum failure". Step 2: apply fix

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to worry about. [LVFS](https://fwupd.org/) updates provide firmware upgrades; a checksum error there won’t affect any of your software upgrades (those you get through `apt-get`).

If necessary you can force a refresh by running

```
sudo fwupdmgr --force refresh
```